# Is using a French press to strain plant milk (almond, soy, etc.) easier than straining through cheesecloth?

Tags: soymilk, french-press, straining

The thing I hate most about making homemade milk is having to squeeze that little bag for eons just to strain all the milk out. I got the idea to do it in a French press instead, but upon doing some research found that people have very mixed experiences with this method.

Is it perhaps dependent on the quality of the French press? Has anyone here tried this way and is it preferable to the cheesecloth / nut milk bag?

Answer (score 1):

I've never made nutmilk, but I'd guess the fine-ness of the nut puree could cause problems. You can put a coffee filter over the metal strainer (so that you push it down into the liquid) to keep particles out, but then you'll still have liquid trapped with the puree under the metal strainer. It'll also be kind of a pain to press down with the paper in there.

If you're okay with losing some of the nutmilk then it may well be easier. But then if you were okay with it, I'd think you wouldn't be so annoyed by the traditional method.

I guess if you use a LOT of puree relative to the amount of water, you could press it directly with the strainer, but even so there's simply a limit to how much you can press in a French press. If you're like me, you'd end up eyeing the puree at the bottom suspiciously, decide to throw it out, then find yourself scraping it into the nutmilk bag anyway and cursing the father of all nuts for making you do this.

Again, I really *don't* know on this one, but I'm guessing it's 6 of one, half a dozen of the other. If you're willing to let the French press tell you "that's enough!" then that method would be easier. If you're thinking you're going to get every last drop, you won't escape the nutmilk bag, and you basically need to decide if you want to wash your French press too.

ALSO, if you use the French press, you'll want to disassemble it and wash it thoroughly in the first place in case it's new for obvious reasons, and in case there is any coffee oil residue if it's been used for coffee. That coffee aroma is hard to escape.

Answer (score 0):

I've never made nutmilk either, but I see an issue…

Does the solid float or sink? If it floats & is very fine you'll never push the handle down; it's enough of a struggle if you grind your coffee too fine. You need to keep pulling the lid off & stirring it. As soon as it floats up & re-clumps you go round again… until eventually after 5 or 6 goes you succeed in reaching the bottom of the press, swearing constantly that you'll never do this again ;)

I'd be tempted towards maybe a cheese press - something you can set up & leave; let the weight do the work.

Comment: Interesting thought with the cheese press, but since that is one thing I've actually done, it would be verrrry difficult to collect the nutmilk without loss and also keep it clean while waiting for the press to do its magic. And as for too fine coffee and the proper abuse of a French press--you should be able to press it without stirring. If it gets seriously stuck, smack it on the side to move things lol. But I don't *think* the nutmilk solids tend to float, regardless. I made a cashew milk sauce once without straining, and that's my memory.

Comment: I'd look for something like a cider press: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cider+press&t=ffsb&ia=shopping  Those have a screw down mechanism which maintains the pressure without you having to lean into it. I don't know that they are made in the size you want, but they are not a terribly hard thing to make at home.

Comment: You might want to consider doing the process in two passes. If you can eliminate 90 percent of solids quickly with one pass, it'll make a second, superclean, pass go a lot faster.